# Using styledText in SWT application

Tags: java, ruby, swt, jruby

I have a simple question really: SWT documentation says that if you're using styledText, you either implements its API or you implement LineStyleListener.

So, If I do use LineStyleListener, how can I still control the representation of specific characters in the editor widget? It seems that implementing LineStyleListener only provides coloring of the whole line at a time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the LineStyleListener you can still add styles for single characters by modifying the provided `StyleRange` array. It is called **Line**StyleListener only because you get the text by lines.

For explanations how to use this, see [here](http://java-gui.info/Wiley-Professional.Java.Interfaces.with.SWT.JFace/12093/BBL0045.html#ch08lev3sec7) or [here](http://java-gui.info/Apress-The.Definitive.Guide.to.SWT.and.JFace/8886final/LiB0100.html).